# k th smallest element in row wise and column wise sorted matrix

Tags: python, heap

Find the kth smallest element in row wise and column wise sorted element:

> Example:
>
> matrix[row][col] < matrix[row+1][col]
>
> matrix[row][col] < matrix[row][col+1]
>
> mat=
>
> > 1  2  21
> >
> > 11 23 25
> >
> > 31 36 41

I have written following code, How to make more readable and improve its complexity:

```
import heapq
def kth_smallest(k, mat):
    m = len(mat)
    n = len(mat[0])
    hp = []
    for i in xrange(n):
           heapq.heappush(hp,[mat[0][i], 0, i])
    heapq.heapify(hp)
    while k >1:
        x = heapq.heappop(hp)
        if x[1]+1 < m:
            heapq.heappush(hp,[mat[x[1]+1][x[2]], x[1]+1, x[2]])           
        heapq.heapify(hp)
        k-=1

    return hp[0][0]


print kth_smallest(8, [[1,10,12],[2,11,21], [3,31,45]])
```

Comment: In the problem statement duplicates are not mentioned. What is the 3rd smallest element in `[[0, 1], [1, 2]]`, `1` or `2`? All our functions would say `1` (yours included).

Answer (score 4):

- `heappush` and `heappop` maintain the heap invariant; there is no need to call `heapify` after them. Alternatively, you could initialize the heap from an unsorted list using `heapify` and skip the `heappush`, but as the list is already sorted in this case, it is already a heap and you don't need to apply either function.
- You push the whole first row to the heap but the first `k` elements would suffice thanks to the rows being already sorted.
- Instead of

  ```
  for i in xrange(n):
         heapq.heappush(hp,[mat[0][i], 0, i])
  ```

  it would be more idiomatic to use

  ```
  for i, value in enumerate(mat[0]):
         heapq.heappush(hp, [value, 0, i])
  ```

  though as I already advised to take only `k` elements, you could instead use

  ```
  for i, value in zip(xrange(k), mat[0]):
  ```
- More idiomatic instead of `while k >1:` ... `k-=1` would be `for _ in xrange(k - 1):`
- Readability of 
  `[mat[x[1]+1][x[2]], x[1]+1, x[2]]`

  could be improved to `[mat[row + 1][col], row + 1, col]`

  by unpacking `value, row, col = heapq.heappop(hp)`

Revised code:

```
def kth_smallest(k, mat):
    '''Return the kth smallest element in row wise and column wise sorted matrix.
    mat represents the matrix as list of lists.
    '''
    m = len(mat)
    hp = [(value, 0, col) for col, value in zip(xrange(k), mat[0])]
    # hp is a min heap because mat[0] is assumed to be sorted
    for _ in xrange(k - 1):
        value, row, col = heapq.heappop(hp)
        row += 1
        if row < m:
            heapq.heappush(hp, (mat[row][col], row, col))           

    return hp[0][0]
```

Comment: I added your code to the timing table in my answer. Obviously your solution scales a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

A very easy way is to hope that list additions and the standard Python sort are fast (the latter being especially fast for partially sorted arrays).

In that case you could have used the second argument of the `sum` function as a starting point for the sum and used:

```
def kth_smallest(k, mat):
    entries = sorted(sum(mat, []))
    return entries[k - 1]
```

On my machine, for the example given, this outperforms your solution for small matrices, but breaks down for larger matrices. It is, however *a lot* easier to understand.

```
+----+---------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| k  |                matrix                 | Graipher | Harsha  | Janne Karila |
+----+---------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
|  1 | [[1,10,12],[2,11,21], [3,31,45]]      | 1.34 µs  | 1.61 µs | 1.07 µs      |
|  8 | [[1,10,12],[2,11,21], [3,31,45]]      | 1.22 µs  | 5.94 µs | 3.72 µs      |
|  8 | [[1,10,12, 25, 38, 42, 51],           | 2.43 µs  | 12 µs   | 5.55 µs      |
|    | [2,11,21, 35, 48, 52, 67],            |          |         |              |
|    | [3,31,45, 47, 58, 63, 72],            |          |         |              |
|    | [4, 32, 46, 48, 59, 64, 73]]          |          |         |              |
| 25 | [range(i, i+50) for i in range(50)]   | 286 µs   | 220 µs  | 42.4 µs      |
| 25 | [range(i, i+100) for i in range(100)] | 1.8 ms   | 455 µs  | 79.3 µs      |
+----+---------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
```

---

Style-wise, there are only a few [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations, all missing whitespace around operators.

Comment: Don't you think `itertools.chain.from_iterable(mat)` would be more idiomatic than `sum(mat, [])`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger You are probably right, will try it out tomorrow. But, I always wanted to find a use for the second argument of `sum`^^

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Performance-wise it is basically the same, with `sum` being slightly faster (by about 0.2 µs).

Comment: This will scale badly, try a bigger array

Answer (score 1):

This problem is already solved in the `heapq` module. If you read more carefully its documentation you'll find [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) whose description boils down to "it's similar to `sorted(itertools.chain(*iterables))` [pretty much as in @Graipher answer] but more efficient".

The last thing left is to extract out the \$k^{th}\$ value out of the returned generator. You can do it manually by using `next` k times or using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to do it for you:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import islice


def kth_smallest(k, mat):
    sorted = merge(*mat)
    sorted_from_k = islice(sorted, k, None)
    try:
        return next(sorted_from_k)
    except StopIteration:
        raise IndexError(k)
```

In case of very large number of rows in the original matrix, you may want to limit their unpacking. You can try slicing:

```
def kth_smallest(k, mat):
    sorted = merge(*mat[:k])
    sorted_from_k = islice(sorted, k, None)
    try:
        return next(sorted_from_k)
    except StopIteration:
        raise IndexError(k)
```